# angular.js : replacing text

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs

I'm new to angular.js.
Below is my first working app. The second text area displays the text typed in the first area.
What's the proper way and how to make it work this way:
the text result is almost the same as in the source, but letters "a" are replaced with "0".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <script src="angular1.2.12.js"/>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea data-ng-model="source"></textarea>
    <textarea id="result">{{source}}</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArVEp/).

Comment: I could edit your Jsfiddle to do what you want to achieve. However, i believe that this won't help you as it would be the shortest possible way to do so and has nothing to do with a 'real world' application. What have you tried so far? Have you completed the tutorial?

Comment: Just started. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a filter applied to the `source` to do the conversion.

```
app.filter('replaceA', function(){
    return function(input){
      return input.replace(new RegExp('a', 'g'), '0');
    }
});
```

Then apply this to your HTML

```
<textarea data-ng-model="source"></textarea>
<textarea id="result">{{ source || '' | replaceA }}</textarea>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranru/m3eQx/)

Comment: JS replace() will only replace the first occurrence.